# Velocity with MySQL DB Connectivity not working

Tags: java, mysql, velocity

I've been trying to create a HTML Page using Velocity which shows the names stored in a SQL Table named users. When I run my program, it prints the following stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5528)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5448)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5488)
    at com.sarvika.velocity.HelloWorld.CfNMHTMLParser.main(CfNMHTMLParser.java:41)
```

I am sure that I did import all the required libraries and the Driver for MySQL Connectivity. I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.6 for the purpose. My code is:

```
package com.sarvika.velocity.dbtovelocity;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.velocity.*;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;

public class CfNMHTMLParser {

private final static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/coffeenet";
private final static String USER = "root";
private final static String PASS = "root";

private static final String BOOL_EXC = "exception";
private static final String EXC = "exc";
private static final String USER_LIST = "usersArray";

    public static void main (String [] args)
            throws IOException {

        VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
        Template template = engine.getTemplate("HTMLTemplate.vm");
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

        CfNMHTMLParser parser = new CfNMHTMLParser();

        String [] data = null ;
        try {

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users ;";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            int count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("count(*)"));

            data = new String[count];

            query = "SELECT AuthID FROM users ;";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
                rs.next();
                data[i] = rs.getString("AuthID");
            }

    //          data = new String [] {
    //                  "developers",
    //                  "developers",
    //                  "developers",
    //                  "developers"
    //          };

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            context.put(BOOL_EXC, true);
            context.put(EXC, ex.getMessage());

        }

        context.put(USER_LIST, data);

        StringWriter templateData = new StringWriter();
        template.merge(context, templateData);

        File htmlFile = new File("page.html");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(htmlFile);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        writer.write(templateData.toString());

        writer.close();

    }

}
```

The file HTMLTemplate.vm

```
#macro( makeUserTable $userListObjArray )
    #foreach( $user in $userListObjArray )
        <font size="7" color="ffccaa">
            $user
        </font>
        <BR>
    #end
#end

<html>

    <title>CoffeeNet Messenger Users</title>

    #if ($exception == true)
        <font size="48">Exception : $exc </font>
    #else
        #makeUserTable( $usersArray )
    #end

</html>
```

Please tell me where I am making the mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. It was not because of

```
    String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users ;";      

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    int count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("count(*)"));
```

Here, what the stack track says

```
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:815)
```

**It is telling us to check the row position, which in this case is nothing.**
The correct code then is

```
    String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users ;"; 

    rs.next();     

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    int count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("count(*)"));
```

Using a column alias is just nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line rs.getString("count(*)") so you can change this two line:

```
String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users ;";
...            
int count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("count(*)"));
```

respectively in :

```
String query = "SELECT count(*) as tot FROM users ;";
...            
int count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("tot"));
```

For Velocity i think that you must init is so you can add this line:

```
    VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
    engine.init(); // line to add
    Template template = engine.getTemplate("HTMLTemplate.vm");
```